# Retrieve callback informations received on the node server

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I firstly have a node js app hosted on a server.
and secondly a callback tier that transmits information in CSV form for my application periodically.

This is the callback setting, this callback who forward the informations (as in line pattern format) to my application situated on the ip address 109...

[image]

I wanted to know how to retrieve and read emit information via the callback on my application Node js

Comment: Hi and welcome on stack overflow. We require that all question be asked in english, so you may want to translate your question title. Also, your question is unclear, could you post the code of what you are trying to do, and indicate what fails, or what you don't know how to realize?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your advices, i just modified my question and added a screen shot.